# django ajax does not work

Tags: python, ajax, django, static

index.html:

```
<head>

{% load staticfiles %}
<script src={% static "/static/jquery.min.js" %}></script>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
xhttp.open("GET", "text.html", true);
xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>

<p id="ajax">hello wordl</p>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
```

and text.html:

```
<p>goodbye</p>
```

Both files are in the same directory (template directory).
Nothing happens by clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I added:

```
def text(request):
    return render(request, 'text.html')
```

into views.py, and this:

```
url(r'^text', text),
```

into urls.py.